# Syncing old phone with new computer - what is this message?

Tags: ios, data-synchronization, icloud, notes.app

I have a new Mac but I'm using my iPhone. Previously I had "Notes" synced between my phone and the old Mac. Now I have notes on my phone that I don't want to lose, and I'm trying to set up the iCloud sync on the new Mac. When I go into the iCloud panel and mark Notes for sync, I get this weird screen:

[image]

I have no idea why it needs an iCloud email address, since I have already set up iCloud and OTHER iCloud services (like Contacts, Calendars & Reminders and Photo Stream) are already set up and syncing perfectly between the phone and the new computer.

My goal is to get Notes syncing without losing any of the important notes on my phone. And I don't want to create a new "iCloud email address" (?!)... please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: back up your phone data.

Then:

1. Open the Notes app on your "new Mac" (I assume you're using Mountain Lion).
2. In the menu bar, select Notes.
3. In the drop down pick list, select Default Account, and make sure iCloud is ticked.

If iCloud doesn't show up, click on Accounts and add it first.